# Open IE and Edge IE with same inner window size

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to open IE and Edge IE mode with exact same inner window size to ensure both browsers display the same content. So, how can I open both browsers with fixed inner window size?

I tried to resize by executing script, but doesn't work.

Below is the code which opens Edge IE mode but resizing does not work.

```cs
var dir = Definition.ContentFilePath;
var driver = "IEDriverServer.exe";
if (!Directory.Exists(dir) || !File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, driver))) {
  Console.WriteLine("Failed to find {0} in {1} folder.", dir, driver);
  Environment.Exit(1);
}
var ieService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(dir, driver);
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions {};
ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgechromium", true);
ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
ieOptions.RequireWindowFocus = true;
ieOptions.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("JavascriptEnabled", true);

var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieService, ieOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
driver.ExecuteScript(@"window.resizeTo(800,800;");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/nim");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript syntax error in your code:

```
driver.ExecuteScript(@"window.resizeTo(800,800;");
                                              ^
----------------------------------------------|
                  (missing closing parenthesis)
```

Looks like you are just missing the closing parenthesis in the call to `window.resizeTo(...)`:

```
driver.ExecuteScript(@"window.resizeTo(800,800);");
                                              ^
----------------------------------------------|
                 (put closing parenthesis here)
```

Comment: Although it changes to that, the code does not work. It seems that `ExecuteScript` does not work.

Comment: @IsseiMorita: can you add more info to your question? Are you getting a javascript error? When you say "it doesn't work" how is it behaving?